# Why is serverside javascript not working when targeting shared data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, enterprise

I am trying to update or add records to a shared data extension using serverside javascript.
The below javascripts only works if I am hard-coding the values. Else nothing happens.
In my data extension, "email" is key and "subscriberkey" is required.

Sample of serverside javascript:

```
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var submitterEmail = Request.GetFormField('EmailAddress');
var sk = Request.GetFormField('sk');
var requestsDE = DataExtension.Init('ENT.Master');
var subscriberSearch = requestsDE.Rows.Lookup(["email"],[submitterEmail]);
if (subscriberSearch.length > 0) {
requestsDE.Rows.Update({fname: Request.GetFormField('firstname')},["email"], [submitterEmail]);}
else { //add
requestsDE.Rows.Add({ //pull into DE
email: Request.GetFormField('EmailAddress'),
fname: Request.GetFormField('firstname'),
subscriberkey: Request.GetFormField('sk')
});
}
```

Same setup has been working before, when not using a shared DE.
The form:

```
<form action="" id="contact_form" method="post">
<input name="firstname" placeholder="Fname" required="" type="text" value=""> 
<input name="EmailAddress" placeholder="E-mailadress" required="" type="text" value="%%=v(@emailaddr)=%%">
<input id="sk" name="sk" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@sk)=%%"> /* gets value from elsewhere - works*/
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

In between the form and the serverside javascript I have a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


  $('#contact_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = 'http://myurl';
  var data = $('#contact_form').serializeArray();


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data
  });

 });

});
```

So any idea why this is not working when targeting a shared DE?
Just works if hard coded in serverside js

Comment: You hardcoded what values?  `FirstName` and `EmailAddress`?

Comment: What's resulting from the AJAX call?  I'd suggest writing the the response to your browser console.

Comment: I'd also suggest utilizing a try/catch block in your SSJS.

Comment: Found the issue! It was too simple and I had just overseen it. One of the fields was removed from the data extension.. so it couldn't map.
Thanks so much fro trying to help :) Adam, if possible, you could remove this question all toghether since it probably wont help anyone else either?